# Lanzar excepcion en caso de que usuario ingresado contenga mas de 10 caracteres

Tags: python

```
try:
    nombre = input("Ingresa nombre: ")
    verificar_nombre = len(nombre)
    
except:
    print("Nombre invalido")

if verificar_nombre >= 10:
    #Que coloco acá?
            
else:
    print("Nombre valido")
```

Cree un código que verifica el nombre de usuario ingresado. El nombre del usuario que es su primer nombre no debe exceder de 10 caracteres.

Pero no encuentro que me funcione la excepción en caso que el codigo que esta en try no se cumpla al hacer la comprobacion. Deseo poder combinar el if-else con el try/except

Comment: Buen día, crear múltiples usuarios va en contra de las normas del sitio, tus preguntas anteriores han sido cerradas y/o votadas negativamente ya que no se apegan a los lineamientos de [ask], en lugar de crear nuevas preguntas con la misma información que las anteriores aplica los comentarios que se te han compartido. Por favor elimina uno de tus usuarios para evitar que tus cuentas puedan ser bloqueadas

Comment: Hola @Osbel Zorrilla, tal vez te sirva esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73855/lanzar-una-excepci%C3%B3n-en-python.

Comment: Lanzar una excepción se hace con el comando `raise` y tendrás que elegir qué clase de excepción quieres lanzar en este caso. Por otro lado la estructura general de tu código no es correcta puesto que el código dentro del try no va a lanzar ninguna excepción en caso de nombre inválido. Y en cambio el código que pones después sí que la lanzaría, pero no estaría siendo manejada.

Comment: ¿Tú eres el mismo Osmer Zorrila?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso del siguiente código, **creado en base al que pasaste** (ya que el try-except no debe utilizarse en estos casos):

```py
try:
    nombre = input("Ingresa nombre: ")
    verificar_nombre = len(nombre)
    if (verificar_nombre > 10):
        raise ValueError("Nombre invalido")
    else:
        print("Nombre valido")

except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

Espero que te sirva, cabe aclarar nuevamente que try-except no es necesario en estos casos, basta con una simple validación haciendo uso de condicionales.

Comment: El error del OP está en que no entiende el try-except, su uso y aplicación. No necesitas excepciones para validar, solo "if"

Comment: @CandidMoe La pregunta es clara: "lanzar excepcion en caso de que...". La respuesta se ajusta a ello. No veo razón para votar negativo.

Comment: @jlgarcia. Es un código horrible. Hay que identificar el real problema del OP, que es no saber validar. Esta respuesta incentiva malas prácticas.

Comment: Ya veo tengo que usar Raise en el If para que asi me funcione y luego agregar except pero debo identificar el tipo de excepcion a lanzar

Comment: @CandidMoe ya se que es un código horrible le faltan un montón de buenas prácticas, la idea es que se facilite la comprensión de lo que se necesita. Por eso inicie mi respuesta con "creado en base al que pasaste" porque sabía que alguien iba a pasar a criticar el código.

Comment: @CandidMoe comprendo que try-except no se utiliza para esto mi error fue no aclararlo debajo :( pero yo no me limito a la pregunta, entiendo que este puede ser un ejemplo que le ayude a comprender la correcta estructuración de un try-except y lo extienda a un uso más complejo y correcto, entenderlo no es sencillo y muchos necesitan de ejemplos simples y de hacer print("hola mundo") para aprender a programar, no nacen sabiendo hacer programación con actores o codigo que manipule una FPGA, o editores del clean code, saludos

Answer (score 2):

Una de las formas correctas de validar este tipo de ingresos es:

- Entrar en un ciclo infinito.
- Pedir el dato.
- Si el dato es válido, salir del ciclo.
- Si el dato no es válido, mostrar error y volver a pedir.

En código:

```
while True:
    nombre = input("Ingresa nombre: ")

    if len(nombre) >= 10:
        print("Nombre debe tener menos de 10 caracteres")
    else:
        break

# Aqui el nombre ha sido correctamente ingresado.
print("Nombre: ", nombre)
```

produce:

```
Ingresa nombre: andres lopez molina riquelma
Nombre debe tener menos de 10 caracteres
Ingresa nombre: andres
Nombre:  andres

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Try-except**

El `try-except` se usa para manejar **excepciones**, situaciones que *no deberían ocurrir* como parte del proceso normal. Que el usuario ingrese cualquier cosa es normal.