# ¿Cuándo usar clases?

Tags: python, poo

Es que yo tengo un poco de conocimiento de Poo y programó en Python, pero es que realmente no he visto cuando usar las clases, no las he usado nunca en mis prácticas (solo soy estudiante) pero me gustaría saber cuando usarlas y cuál sería la mejor manera. Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Diego, es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento. Para realizar preguntas y estas sean bien recibidas debes revisar primero [ask]. Te sugiero leas la documentación: http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/3/classes.html y posteriormente realices preguntas especificas, saludos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Antes de preguntar, aségurate que sea una pregunta menos abierta, porfavor; pero bienvenido a SO! :D***

---

Para responder a tu pregunta de una forma simple, las clases se utilizan cuando quieres realizar una abstracción de un objeto de la vida real **(De ahí viene la POO)**, como por ejemplo: Un carro, una persona, una casa...

Algo importante que debes notar, es que **Objetos** así, sus clases se utilizan en *singular*, no en plural.

```
class Persona:
    ..atributos y métodos..
```

En una `clase`, Persona en éste caso, puedes definir atributos de la clase:

```
class Persona:

    def __init__(self, nombre, genero, edad):
        self._nombre = nombre
        self._genero = genero
        self._edad = edad
```

Lo que pasa ahí, se utiliza [`__init__`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79502/duda-con-clases-para-que-sirve-init) para inicializar los atributos o cualquier otra variable **de la clase**; supongo que ya has de saber qué son parametros y argumentos, así que me saltaré esa parte. 
`self` es como el `this`, pero de Python, la verdad puedes renombrarlo a lo que quieras pero eso es una horrible práctica.

Luego puedes crear instancias de la clase:

```
pepe = Persona('Pepe','H',22) #Creamos un objeto de la clase Persona, llamado Pepe, Hombre y de 22 años.
```

Ya luego le puedes ir poniendo más métodos, atributos...

**EN RESUMEN:** Las clases nos sirven para poder llevar a un plano abstracto o imaginario, objetos de la vida real; pueden tener atributos (tamaño, nombre, color...), métodos (Modificar algo, borrar algo, o hacer algo en general) y creas objetos de ellos (Osea, creas una nueva instancia de esa clase, con diferentes atributos).

Te recomiendo bastante leer la documentación de Python.

Suerte ;)