# ¿Por qué llamar directamente al __init__() de una clase no me instancia el objeto?

Tags: python, poo, constructor

Estoy dando mis primeros pasos en Python no entiendo porque el constructor no coge correctamente los parámetros, el código es el siguiente:

```
numeroElementos=1
lista=[]

class Range:

    def __init__(self, start, end, step):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.step = step
        lista = [self.start]
        if lista[numeroElementos-1] < self.end:
            lista[numeroElementos] = self.start + self.step        

    def __len__(self,lista):
       return numeroElementos

    def __getItem__(self,elemento):
       return lista[elemento-1]

comienzo = int(input("Introduce el valor de inicio\n"))
fin = int(input("Introduce la cota superior\n"))
paso = int(input("Introduce el espacio entre pasos\n"))
Range.__init__(comienzo, fin, paso)
```

La consola arroja el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'step'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método `__init__` **no es realmente el constructor de la clase**, es el  inicializador de la clase (`__init__`) y **es llamado automáticamente** cuando se instancia dicha clase si el verdadero constructor (`__new__`) retorna una instancia válida de la clase.

Por tanto, llamar a `__init__` directamente no genera una instancia de la clase (trabajo de `__new__`), el inicializador a grandes rasgos permite definir un estado inicial para una instancia de la clase previamente existente generada por `__new__`.

Por lo general a `__init__` no se le llama directamente de forma explícita excepto en casos especiales, quizás el más común es la herencia en la que sobrescribimos el método `__init__` en una clase hija pero queremos que el inicializador del padre o padres sea llamado también:

```
class Padre:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Inicializador de Padre llamado")
        self.foo = 4


class Hija(Padre):
    def __init__(self):
        # Sobrescribimos el __init__ heredado de Padre
        print("Inicializador de Hija llamado")
```

> ```
> >>> hija = Hija()
> Inicializador de Hija llamado
>
> >>> hija.foo
> AttributeError: 'Hija' object has no attribute 'foo'
> ```

Como vemos el inicializador del padre ha sido solapado por el del hijo, esto hace que no sea llamado y por tanto el atributo `foo` no existe en la instancia de `Hija`. Si queremos que el inicializador del padre sea llamado si ha sido sobrescrito en la clase hija, debemos hacerlo de forma explícita:

```
class Padre:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Inicializador de Padre llamado")
        self.foo = 4


class Hija(Padre):
    def __init__(self):
        # Sobrescribimos el __init__ heredado de Padre
        Padre.__init__(self)
        print("Inicializador de Hija llamado")
```

> ```
> >>> hija = Hija()
> Inicializador de Padre llamado
> Inicializador de Hija llamado
>
> >>> hija.foo
> 4
> ```

Aunque es recomendable [usar `super`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/130241/15089) para esto:

```
super().__init__()
```

En tu caso, por tanto, simplemente instancia la clase y pasa los tres argumentos:

```
Range(comienzo, fin, paso)
```

El error se debe a que el inicializador recibe realmente cuatro parámetros, siendo el primero como en cualquier método de instancia la referencia a la propia instancia de la clase a la que pertenece el método, por convención se nombra con `self` (aunque técnicamente podemos llamarlo como quramos). Este parámetro **se pasa de forma automática al llamar a cualquier método de instancia que sea llamado mediante una referencia a una instancia de la clase,** incluido el inicializador. Tu lo llamas a través de una referencia a la clase, no a una instancia de la misma, por lo que `self` (instancia) ni existe ni se pasa de forma automática por tanto.

El método tal como lo llamas recibe los siguientes argumentos realmente:

```
Rango.__init__(self=comienzo, start=fin, end=paso)
```

por lo que a `step` no se le asigna nada y de ahí el error que te muestra.

Para más información mirate estas dos preguntas:

- [¿Qué es un constructor?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63407/qu%c3%a9-es-un-constructor)
- [Duda con clases. ¿Para que sirve __init__?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79502/duda-con-clases-para-que-sirve-init/79522#79522)

Por otro lado, tienes otras inconsistencias en tu clase:

- Defines una variable `lista` a nivel global y además defines otra variable `lista` en el inicializador. Esto hace que en el `__init__` la variable global sea solapada por la local y se use la lista que defines en él y en `__getItem__` la lista definida globalmente.
- Creo que con `__getItem__` en realidad te refieres al método especial `__getitem__` que te permite indizar e iterar sobre el objeto.
- La variable `numeroElementos` no es definida en ningún lado.
- Sea como sea, no debes usar variables globales para nada en este caso, menos si usas POO. Usa [atributos de instancia (si van a ser diferentes para cada instancia) o atributos de clase (si van a ser compartidos por las distintas instancias de la clase)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/132561/diferencia-entre-atributos-de-instancia-y-atributos-de-clase/132570#132570).

Presupongo que intentas implementar algo parecido a `range` de Python 2.x, en tal caso y siguiendo un poco tu propia idea podrías hacer algo así (muy simplificado):

```
class Range:

    def __init__(self, start, end, step):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.step = step
        self.lista = []
        self.item = self.start
        while self.item < self.end:
            self.lista.append(self.item)
            self.item += self.step

    def __len__(self):
       return len(self.lista)

    def __getitem__(self, elemento):
       return self.lista[elemento]

comienzo = int(input("Introduce el valor de inicio\n"))
fin = int(input("Introduce la cota superior\n"))
paso = int(input("Introduce el espacio entre pasos\n"))
rango = Range(comienzo, fin, paso)
```

> ```
> Introduce el valor de inicio
> 3
>
> Introduce la cota superior
> 16
>
> Introduce el espacio entre pasos
> 2
>
> >>> for item in rango:
>         print(item)        
> 3
> 5
> 7
> 9
> 11
> 13
> 15
>
> >>> rango[4]
> 11
> >>> len(rango)
> 7
> ```

Comment: Mil gracias, la verdad es que tengo un poco de lío con el self,  viniendo de java hay bastantes cosas de la sintaxis bastante diferentes.

Comment: Gracias por volver @FJSevilla, no nos dejes más