# Ingresar datos a listas por medio de __init__

Tags: python, lista

Tengo hecho el 'constructor' pero no puedo ingresar los campos que quiero (en este caso son 3, nombre, e-mail y no. control). Lo que quiero hacer es llenar los 3 campos y que cada registro sea una lista, y cada una añadirla a la lista principal.
Al final me imprime las listas vacías dentro de la lista principal, por lo mismo de que no tengo datos...

Código:

```
print("Registra a los alumnos en la siguiente lista. \n Cuando termines, ingresa 'YA'")
l2 = []
ya = ""
while ya.lower() != "ya":
    l = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.nombre = l.append(input("Nombre: "))
        self.email = l.append(input("e-mail: "))
        self.control = l.append(int(input("No. Control: ")))
    l2.append(l)
    ya = input("Si vas a registrar más alumnos, ingresa 'M'; si no, 'YA'")

print("Los alumnos que registraste son:\n")
print(l2)
```

Salida de la consola de Python:

```
Registra a los alumnos en la siguiente lista. 
 Cuando termines, ingresa 'YA'
Si vas a registrar más alumnos, ingresa 'M'; si no, 'YA'aw
Si vas a registrar más alumnos, ingresa 'M'; si no, 'YA'aw
Si vas a registrar más alumnos, ingresa 'M'; si no, 'YA'yA
Los alumnos que registraste son:

[[], [], []]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero, estás definiendo un método `__init__` (inicializador de una clase) fuera de una, además lo haces dentro de un ciclo y encima nunca lo llamas siquiera (aunque de nada serviría).

Además, ten en cuenta que, de funcionar, hacer:

```
self.nombre = l.append(input("Nombre: "))
```

hace que `self.nombre` sea siempre `None`, retorno de `list.append`.

Te recomiendo primero mirarte:

- [¿Qué es un constructor?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/63407/15089)
- [Duda con clases. ¿Para que sirve __init__?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/79502/15089)

Dado que dices:

> Lo que quiero hacer es llenar los 3 campos y que cada registro sea una lista

Supongo que la salida que buscas es algo como:

```
[["Fulanito", "fulanito@mail.com", 123], ["Menganito", "menganito@mail.com", 124]]
```

En tal caso, el método simplemente no pinta nada aquí:

```
print("Registra a los alumnos en la siguiente lista. \n Cuando termines, ingresa 'YA'")
l2 = []
ya = ""
while ya.lower() != "ya":
    nombre = input("Nombre: ")
    email = input("e-mail: ")
    control = int(input("No. Control: "))
    l2.append([nombre,  email,  control])
    ya = input("Si vas a registrar más alumnos, ingresa 'M'; si no, 'YA'")

print("Los alumnos que registraste son:\n")
print(l2)
```

> ```
> Registra a los alumnos en la siguiente lista. 
>  Cuando termines, ingresa 'YA'
> Nombre: Fulanito
> e-mail: fulanito@mail.com
> No. Control: 123
> Si vas a registrar más alumnos, ingresa 'M'; si no, 'YA'M
> Nombre: Menganito
> e-mail: menganito@email.com
> No. Control: 124
> Si vas a registrar más alumnos, ingresa 'M'; si no, 'YA'YA
> Los alumnos que registraste son:
>
> [['Fulanito', 'fulanito@mail.com', 123], ['Menganito', 'menganito@email.com', 124]]
> ```

Otra posibilidad, buscándole sentido al uso del inicializador, sería que implementaras una clase `Alumno` y tu lista fuera una lista de objetos `Alumno`:

```
class Alumno:
    def __init__(self, nombre: str, email: str, control: int) -> None:
        self.nombre: str = nombre
        self.email: str = email
        self.control: int = control

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return (f"{self.__class__.__name__}("
                f"nombre='{self.nombre}', "
                f"email='{self.email}', "
                f"control={self.control})"
                )


print("Registra a los alumnos en la siguiente lista. \n Cuando termines, ingresa 'YA'")
alumnos = []
ya = ""
while ya.lower() != "ya":
    nombre = input("Nombre: ")
    email = input("e-mail: ")
    control = int(input("No. Control: "))
    alumnos.append(Alumno(nombre,  email,  control))
    ya = input("Si vas a registrar más alumnos, ingresa 'M'; si no, 'YA'")

print("Los alumnos que registraste son:\n")
print(alumnos)
```

> ```
> Registra a los alumnos en la siguiente lista. 
>  Cuando termines, ingresa 'YA'
> Nombre: Fulanito
> e-mail: fulanito@mail.com
> No. Control: 123
> Si vas a registrar más alumnos, ingresa 'M'; si no, 'YA'M
> Nombre: Menganito
> e-mail: menganito@mail.com
> No. Control: 124
> Si vas a registrar más alumnos, ingresa 'M'; si no, 'YA'YA
> Los alumnos que registraste son:
>
> [Alumno(nombre='Fulanito', email='fulanito@mail.com', control=123),
>  Alumno(nombre='Menganito', email='menganito@mail.com', control=124)]
> ```