# porque no me reconoce el template?

Tags: python, django

Estoy haciendo un sistema web en vsc con python y django. Tengo una app creada "Appmensajeria" donde en el archivo views.py tengo una vista que renderiza un template con un formulario para crear un mensaje y enviarlo. Cuando quiero renderizar ese template no me lo reconoce... Que puede estar pasanado?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añade el código settings.py que hace referencia a la configuración de Templates para que veamos cómo lo tienes configurado. Verás que por otro lado a uno le has llamado "template" al otro "templates".
En DIRS debes indicar que reconozca directorios con nombre templates. Y por otro lado, si utilizas directorio templates dentro de apps, APP_DIRS debes indicarlo en True, si no es así, no revisará dentro de los app si tienes templates. También añade **init**.py a los directorios templates para que django los reconozca.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR, 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me faltaba esas modificaciones en el archivo settings.py del proyecto...

Comment: No entendi lo del init.py... De todas formas asi me funciono. Pero para que serviria agregarle el init.py?

Comment: __init__.py aunque su explicación y funcionamiento será muy técnico, podemos entenderlo para indicar a django que ese directorio existe y es parte del proyecto. Más detalle aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79502/duda-con-clases-para-que-sirve-init