# ¿Cual es mi error en este código para poder mostrar a los usuarios?

Tags: python

Me estoy iniciando en clases en este excelente lenguaje y tengo el siguiente código:

```
class usuario: #clase con la que defino que parametros voy a capturar
    def __init__(self, id, nombre, apellido, edad, tiempo_conocido, asignado): #asignacion del metodo con las variables necesarias
        self.id = id
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellido = apellido        #Asignacion de variables al metodo
        self.edad = edad
        self.tiempo_conocido = tiempo_conocido
        self.asignado = asignado
        self.lista = lista

def Captura():
    usuario.asignado = int(input("Usuarios a capturar (maximo 5!!): "))
    for i in range(0, usuario.asignado): #Con este for agrego los usuarios de manera consecutiva en el rango establecido
        usuario.id = input("\nId del usuario: ")
        usuario.nombre = input("Nombre del usuario: ")
        usuario.apellido = input("Apellido del usuario: ")
        usuario.edad = input("Edad del usuario: ")
        usuario.tiempo_conocido = input("Tiempo de haber conocido al usuario: ")    
        usuario.final = usuario.asignado

def MuestraUsuario():   #Funcion que me permite mostrar a los usuarios capturados...
    for i in range(0, usuario.final):
        print ("\nId del usuario: ", usuario.id)
        print ("El nombre fue: ", usuario.nombre)
        print ("El apellido del usuario fue: ", usuario.apellido)
        print ("La edad fue: ", usuario.edad)
        print ("El tiempo de haberlo conocido fue de: ", usuario.tiempo_conocido)      


def BuscarUsuario():
    a = input("Qué dato busco? ")
    if a in usuario.nombre or a in usuario.id or a in usuario.apellido or a in usuario.edad or a in usuario.tiempo_conocido:
        print("*****************************")
        print ("*El elemento se encuentra!  *")
        print("*****************************")

    else:
        print("*****************************")
        print("*El elemento no esta...      *") 
        print("*****************************")        

def Ordenar():
  pass    

def menu():
    print ("Menu de usuarios! \nSelecciona una opcion: \n1.Captura\n2.Muestra de los datos capturados\n3.Busca algun dato\n4.Ordenar los elementos\n5.Salir")
    a = int(input("\nSeleccion: "))

    if a == 1:
        Captura()
        b = int(input("Deseas regresar al menu? 1 = si 2 = no: "))
        if b == 1:
            menu()
        if b == 2:
            print ("Hasta luego!")
    if a == 2:
        MuestraUsuario()
        b = int(input("Deseas regresar al menu? 1 = si 2 = no: "))
        if b == 1:
            menu()
        if b == 2:
            print ("Hasta luego!")        

    if a == 3:
        BuscarUsuario()
        b = int(input("Deseas regresar al menu? 1 = si 2 = no: "))
        if b == 1:
            menu()
        if b == 2:
            print ("Hasta luego!")        

    if a == 4:
        Ordenar()
        b = int(input("Deseas regresar al menu? 1 = si 2 = no: "))
        if b == 1:
            menu()
        if b == 2:
            print ("Hasta luego!")                


    if a == 5:
        print ("Hasta luego!")

menu()
```

Mi problema es que no logro hacer que en mi función `mostrar` me despliegue los usuarios que capturo (solo logro mostrar 1). ¿Cuál es el error?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que **en ningún momento estas instanciando nuevos objetos de la clase y tampoco guardas las referencias de cada uno** de ellos en algún contenedor, de forma que puedas luego iterar sobre todos los usuarios y hacer referencia a cada una de las instancias.

Cuando haces `usuario.id` estás **creando un nuevo atributo de clase** llamado `id` (que es compartido por todas las instancias) en vez de dar un valor al atributo de instancia `id` mediante el `__init__`. (Puedes mirarte esta pregunta relacionada para más información: [Diferencia entre variables de instancia y variable de clase en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/132561/15089))

Un ejemplo para ilustrarlo usando una lista:

```
class Usuario:
    def __init__(id, nombre, apellido):
        self.id = id
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellido  = apellido


# Lista que contendrá las referencias de cada uno de las instancias de Usuario
usuarios = []

for _ in range(1):
    # Instanciamos un nuevo objeto y pasando los argumentos al inicializador
    usuario = Usuario(1455, "Pedro", "García")
    # Añadimos la nueva instancia a la lista
    usuarios.append(usuario)

# Ahora podemos iterar sobre los usuarios
for usuario in usuarios:
    print(usuarios.nombre)
```

Un ejemplo de cómo podría quedar tu código es:

```
class Usuario:
    def __init__(self, id, nombre, apellido, edad, tiempo_conocido):
        self.id = id
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellido = apellido
        self.edad = edad
        self.tiempo_conocido = tiempo_conocido

    def __str__(self):
        cad  = ("Id del usuario: {}\n"
                "El nombre es: {}\n"
                "El apellido del usuario es: {}\n"
                "La edad es: {}\n"
                "El tiempo de haberlo conocido es: {}"
                )
        return cad.format(self.id, self.nombre, self.apellido,
                          self.edad, self.tiempo_conocido
                          )      


def capturar_usuarios():
    usuarios = []

    while True:
        n = int(input("Usuarios a capturar (máximo 5): "))
        if  0 < n <= 5:
            break
        print("Numero de usuarios a capturar no válido")

    for _ in range(n):
        id = input("\nId del usuario: ")
        nombre = input("Nombre del usuario: ")
        apellido = input("Apellido del usuario: ")
        edad = input("Edad del usuario: ")
        tiempo_conocido = input("Tiempo de haber conocido al usuario: ")    

        # Creamos una nueva instancia de la clase usuario
        usuario = Usuario(id, nombre, apellido, edad, tiempo_conocido)
        # Añadimos el objeto a a la lista
        usuarios.append(usuario)

    return usuarios    

def mostrar_usuarios(usuarios):
    for usuario in usuarios:
        print("=======================================================")
        print(usuario) # Llama automáticamente al método __str__ de la instancia
    print("=======================================================")    

def buscar_usuario(usuarios):
    pass

def ordenar_usuarios(usuarios):
    pass

def main():
    usuarios = []

    print("¡Menu de usuarios!\n########################",)

    while True:
        print("\nSelecciona una opcion:",
              "  1. Captura",
              "  2. Muestra de los datos capturados",
              "  3. Buscar algun dato",
              "  4. Ordenar los elementos",
              "  5. Salir\n", sep="\n"
              )

        opt = input("Seleccion: ")

        if opt == '1':
            usuarios = capturar_usuarios()

        elif opt == '2':
            mostrar_usuarios(usuarios)      

        elif opt == '3':
            buscar_usuario(usuarios)       

        elif opt == '4':
            ordenar_usuarios(usuarios)

        elif opt == '5':
            print ("¡Hasta luego!")
            return

        else:
            print("No ha ingresado una opción válida. Por favor intentelo de nuevo.")
            continue

        while True:
            opt = input("\n¿Deseas regresar al menu? (s/n): ").lower()
            if opt == 's' or opt == "si":
                break
            elif opt == 'n' or opt == "no":
                print ("¡Hasta luego!")
                return
            else:
                print ("Opción no válida.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Ejemplo de ejecución.

Hay bastantes modificaciones con respecto al código inicial:

- El menú se implementa de forma iterativa y no con llamadas recursivas (es más intuitivo y eficiente generalmente y no hay peligro de alcanzar el límite de recursión). Se usa `if-elif-else` en vez de `if` consecutivos, la diferencia es que en el momento en el que el `if` o un `elif` se cumple el resto no es evaluado siquiera. Si todos son `if` se evalúan todos aunque solo uno sea cierto, lo cual es mucho menos eficiente.
- Ya que estamos trabajando con clases se usa el método especial `__str__` para mostrar la información del usuario. Este método retorna una cadena y es llamado automáticamente cuando se imprime el objeto (`print(objeto)`).
- Se ha renombrado la clase y las funciones para seguir [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Te aconsejo mirarlo cuando tengas tiempo/ganas,  es una guía de estilo oficial para el código Python, son solo convenciones, pero ayudan a estandarizar tu código y a facilitar la legibilidad por terceros (una de las razones de ser de Python).

Hay muchas más cosas que podemos hacer o enfoques distintos, por ejemplo sería adecuado validar los datos ingresados para crear cada instancia de `Usuario`, bien en la propia función `capturar_usuarios` o en la clase vía [`properties`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#property) por ejemplo.

Comment: simplemente impecable, veo que me falta indagar bastante sobre las clases en Python. En serio, muchas gracias por tan elaborada y limpia respuesta. Ya con esto me voy dando más una idea de como debo estar trabajando. Nuevamente, gracias!