# Listas como atributos en objetos en python

Tags: python, class

Tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo una lista de objetos, cada objeto tiene como atributo una lista, mi problema es que asigno la lista al objeto y por alguna razón se hace eco a todas los objetos en la lista.

El código es bastante simple:

```
class Aspirantes:
    stat=1 #1 es free, 2 prometido 3 comprometido 
    proposed= False
    preference=[]

    def __init__(self, status, propos, nombre):
        self.name=nombre
        self.stat=status
        self.proposed=propos



    def setPreference(self, listaprefs):
        print("fijando la lista "+self.name)
        for j in listaprefs:
            self.preference.append(j)



aspirantList = []

aspirantList.append(Aspirantes(2,False,"Daniel"))
aspirantList.append(Aspirantes(3,False,"Rick"))  
aspirantList.append(Aspirantes(1,True,"Agustin"))

aspirantList[0].setPreference({"K","Ke", "Ki"})
aspirantList[2].setPreference({"Ke","K", "Ki"})
aspirantList[1].setPreference({"Ki","Ke", "K"})

for i in range(len(aspirantList)):
    print(aspirantList[i].name)
    print(aspirantList[i].preference)
    for j in range(len(aspirantList[i].preference)):
        print(i)
        print(aspirantList[i].preference[j])
```

Comment: El atributo `preference` es un atributo de clase, no de instancia por lo que es común a todas las instancias de la clase (a lo que hay que sumarle que las listas son mutables) mírate:  [Diferencia entre variables de instancia y variable de clase en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/132561/15089).

Comment: Gracias, creo que mi concepto no era el adecuado.

Comment: Primero de todo Raúl, bienvenido a [es.so]. Segundo, he marcado la pregunta como duplicada porque creo que básicamente el problema se reduce a la duda planteada en esa pregunta, además en mi respuesta casualmente uso una lista para explicar exactamente el comportamiento que tu muestras. No obstante, si tienes cualquier duda no dudes en comentar. Un saludo.