# Listas compartidas en instancias de clases (objetos)

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, lista

Tengo el siguiente código

---

```
class Num(object):

    i = list()
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def imp(self):
        print(self.__i)

    def add(self, n):
        self.__i.append(n)
```

---

```
from Num import *

n1 = Num()
n2 = Num()

n1.add(10)
n1.imp()

n2.add(1)
n2.imp()
```

---

y obtengo el siguiente resultado

- En la impresión de n1 obtengo 10
- En la impresión de n2 obtengo 10,1

Mi duda es , ¿Por qué si son 2 objetos diferentes hace un `append` a la misma lista?

Se supone que si solo modifico la lista del objeto `n1` o `n2` debería tener los valores definidos para cada objeto.

Comment: ¿No debería ser `__i = list()`? Tal y como está tu código no es válido. Si es así, tu lista es un atributo de clase no de instancia por lo que **se comparte entre todas las instancias de la clase** y además es mutable.  Si quieres que sea propio de cada instancia lo debes definir en el `__init__` Mírate: [Diferencia entre atributos de instancia y atributos de clase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/132561/15089).

Comment: Por otro lado Bashunter,  bienvenido a [es.so]. Voy a votar su cierre por  duplicado porque  aparentemente en esencia el error se debe a usar un atributo de clase cuando lo que quieres es un atributo de instancia. En mi respuesta a la pregunta enlazada al final se explica porqué pasa lo que te ocurre a ti con la lista por ser mutable. De todas formas cualquier duda comenta, si fuera necesario y de terminar terminara cerrada, la pregunta puede ser reabierta sin problemas si la edición indica que no se soluciona con las respuestas del duplicado. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que creaste una variable la cual es compartida entre todas las instancias de la clase. Para evitar eso, prueba definiendolas dentro de `__init__`:

```
class Num(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__i = list()

    def imp(self):
        print(self.__i)

    def add(self, n):
        self.__i.append(n)
```

De esta forma las variable se volverán locales a cada instancia de la clase `Num`.