# Estoy haciendo una pokedex y tengo un error a momento de ejecutar la funcion de comida, lo imprime en binarios

Tags: python

```
import os
import sys
import marshal
import requests
import datetime
from datetime import date
from string import Template
pokemones = []
url_api=" http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"

class pokemon():
    nombre = ""
    tipo   = ""
    latitud = ""
    longitud = ""
    comida = ""
    sangre = ""
    ano = ""
    mes = ""
    dia = ""
    edad = ""
    signo = ""
    foto = ""
try:
    a = open("datos.pokemon","br")
    tmp = marshal.load(a)
    for z in tmp:
        p = pokemon()
        p.nombre = z[0]
        p.tipo = z[1]
        p.latitud = z[2]
        p.longitud = z[3]
        p.comida = z[4]
        p.sangre = z[5]
        p.ano = z[6]
        p.mes= z[7]
        p.dia = z[8]
        p.edad = z[9]
        p.signo = z[10]
        p.foto = z[11]
        pokemones.append(p)
    a.close()
    print("Hemos encontrador ", len(pokemones),"pokemones regristrado")
except:
    print("No hay datos regristrados...")

def menu():
    os.system("cls")
    print("---------Bienvenido a la Pokedex--------")
    print("1-Agregar pokemon")
    print("2-Ver pokemon")
    print("3-Reportes")
    print("4-Exportar pokemon")
    print("5-Exportar Mapa")
    print("6-Exit")
    tmp = input("Digite una opcion: ")
    if (tmp =="1"):
        agregarPokemon()
    elif (tmp =="2"):
        verPokemon()
    elif (tmp =="3"):
        reportes()
    elif (tmp == "4"):
        exportarPokemon()
    elif (tmp == "5"):
        exportarMapa()
    elif(tmp =="6"):
        datos = []
        for p in pokemones :
            t=[]

            t.append(p.nombre)
            t.append(p.tipo)
            t.append(p.latitud)
            t.append(p.longitud)
            t.append(p.comida)
            t.append(p.sangre)
            t.append(p.ano)
            t.append(p.mes)
            t.append(p.dia)
            t.append(p.edad)
            t.append(p.signo)
            t.append(p.foto)
            datos.append(t)
        a = open("datos.pokemon","bw")
        marshal.dump(datos,a)
        a.close()
        print("Hasta la proxima")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Digite una opcion valida")
        menu()
def agregarPokemon():
    print("Vamos a agregar Pokemon")
    p = pokemon()
    nombre = input("Digite el nombre del pokemon:")
    print("Estamos validando...")  
    url = url_api + nombre.lower()
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("El pokemon que tenemos es:",nombre)
        pass
    data = response.json()
    (data["types"])

    types_pokemon = ",".join([t["type"]["name"]for t in data["types"]])
    print("Su tipo es:")
    types_pokemon = []
    for t in data["types"]:
        types_pokemon.append(t["type"]["name"])
    for s in types_pokemon:
        print(s)
    if response.status_code == 404:
        print("no lo encuentra")
        print("digite un nombre valido")

    p.nombre = nombre
    print("Esta es la fecha de hoy")
    p.tipo = s
    hoy = datetime.date.today()
    print(hoy.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
    print("Ahora pon la fecha de nacimiento de pokemon")
    p.ano = int(input("Digite su ano de nacimiento \n"))
    p.mes = int (input("Digite su mes de nacimiento \n"))
    p.dia = int(input("Digite su dia de nacimiento \n"))
    d= date.today()
    Calculando= (d.year)-(p.ano)
    Calculando2= (Calculando)-1
    if p.mes>d.month:
        print("su edad es:  "+str(Calculando2))
    elif p.dia>d.day:
        print("su edad es:  "+str(Calculando2))
    elif p.mes<=d.month:
        print("su edad es:  "+str(Calculando))
    elif p.dia<=d.day:
        print("su edad es:  "+str(Calculando))
    p.edad = input("Digite la edad que te muestra la pantalla \n")
    print("Muy bien")
    p.latitud = input("Digite su latitud \n")
    p.longitud = input("Digite su longitud \n")
    p.sangre = input("Digite su tipo de sangre \n")
    p.comida = input("Digite su comida \n")    
    signo = ("capricornio", "acuario", "piscis", "aries", "tauro", "géminis", "cáncer", "leo", "virgo", "libra", "escorpio", "sagitario")
    fechas = (20, 19, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 21)
    dia=p.dia
    mes=p.mes

    mes=mes-1
    if dia>fechas[mes]:
        mes=mes+1
    if mes==12:
        mes=0

        print ("Tu signo zodiaco es: " + signo[mes])
    p.signo = signo[mes]
    pokemones.append(p)
    input("Pokemon agregado,presione enter para volver a opcion")
    menu()
def verPokemon():
    print("Exixten",len(pokemones),"pokemon")
    s = 1
    for p in pokemones:
        print("#--Nombre: ",p.nombre)
        print("#--Latitud: ",p.latitud)
        print("#--longitud: ",p.longitud)
        print("#--Su fecha de nacimiento es: ",p.dia,"/",p.mes,"/",p.ano)
        print("#--Su tipo de sangre es: ",p.sangre)
        print("#--Su tipo de comida: ",p.comida)
        print("#--Su edad es: ",p.edad)
        print("#--El pokemon es de tipo: ",p.tipo)
        print("#--Su signo zodiacal es: ",p.signo)
        s +=1
        print('Gracias por tu estadia aqui!')
    input("Press enter para volver al menu")
    menu()
def reportes():

    print("Veremos los pokemones de mi sistema")
    print("1-Pokemones por cumpleanos")
    print("2-Pokemones por tipo")
    print("3-Pokemones que comida")
    opcion = input("Elige una opcion: ")
    if (opcion == "1"):
        cumpleanos()
    elif (opcion == "2"):
        tipo()
    elif (opcion == "3"):
        comida()
    else:
        print("Elige una opcion valida")
        reportes()
def cumpleanos():
    print("Aqui vamos a encontrar los pokemones que cumpleanos por mes")
    ap = int(input("Digite el mes en numero: "))
    for h in pokemones:
        if ap == int(h.mes):
            print("Nombre",h.nombre)
    else:
        pass
    input("Precione enter para ir a menu principa")
    menu()
def tipo():
    if opcion=="2":
            ti="electric"
            cont=0
            for x in pokemones:
                if ti ==(x.tipo):
                    cont=cont+1
                    print("Hay:",cont,x.tipo)

    else:
        pass
        menu()
def comida():
    print("Aqui vamos a encontrar a los pokemones por comidas")
    for pokemon in pokemones:
        j = []
        j.append(p.comida)
        j.append(p.comida)
        print(pokemon)
    else:
        pass
    input("Precione enter para ir a menu principa")
    menu()

def  exportarPokemon():
    filein = open("Template/Perfil.html")
    src = Template(filein.read())
    nombre = p.nombre
    latitud = p.latitud
    longitud = p.longitud
    fecha_nac = p.dia,p.mes,p.ano
    tipo_sang = p.sangre
    tipo_com = p.comida
    tipo = p.tipo
    signo = p.signo
    edad = p.edad


    d={"nombre":nombre, "latitud":latitud, "longitud":longitud, "fecha_nac":fecha_nac,"edad":edad,
         "tipo_sang":tipo_sang,"tipo_com":tipo_com,"tipo":tipo,"signo":signo,}
    result = src.substitute(d)

    try:
        os.mkdir("Pokemones")
        filein2 = open("pokemones/"+str(nombre)+".html", "w")
        filein2.writelines(result)

        print("Creando una carpeta")
        print("Guardando archivo")

    except OSError:
        if os.path.exists("Pokemones"):
            filein2= open("Pokemones"+".html", "a")
            filein2.writelines(result)
            print("guardando archivo")

    while True:
        question = input("Press S si quieres seguir y E si quieres salir")
        if question == "S":
            os.system("Combazoo.py")
        elif question == "E":
            sys.exit()
menu()
```

Comment: Hola Manuel, ¿podrías explicar un poco mejor que quieres decir con "lo imprime en binarios"? ¿Qué es lo que imprime? ¿la variable `pokemon`? ¿Podrías agregar la salida? Para empezar `p` no está definido y `print(pokemon)` te imprime la instancia, algo como `<__main__.pokemon object at 0x7f1c07f01fd0>`. Por cierto, no uses atributos de clase en tu clase `pokemon`, usa atributos de instancia que es lo que son en tu caso; [Diferencian entre atributos de instancia y atributos de clase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/132561/15089).

Comment: Sii haci mismo me lo imprime

Comment: Estos es lo que quiero que alga pero primero tengo que solucionar ese error...
Ejemplo:En este reporte mostrara cada uno de los tipos de pokemon que existen en nuestro sistema y sus comidas favoritas. Ejemplo: Fire => Arroz con habichuela, moro, aguacate, etc.  Whater => Sopa, Asopao, Sancocho, etc

Comment: Estocen viene y me lo imprime haci <__main__.pokemon object at 0x000000882449D128>..Y no me deja proceder con el programa

Comment: Con `for pokemon in pokemones` iteras sobre la lista `pokemones` (variable global) por lo que `pokemon` son objetos de la clase `pokemon` y al hacer `print(pokemon)` te muestra lo que toda instancia sin método `__str__` definido  muestra,  su clase y la dirección de memoria del objeto... Para que al hacer `print(objeto)` te imprima algo personalizado debes definir el método `__str__` en la clase, ¿Qué se supone que quieras que te imprima cuando haces `print(pokemon)`? Porque si fuera la comida, deberías hacer `print(pokemon.comida)` para que muestre el atributo...

Comment: Entiendo...
Por ejemplo, yo agregue varios pokemones tipo electric....Entoces en la comida favoriti, en uno puse carne y en el otro puse arroz.
Y me va a imprimir = electric, arroz, carne

Comment: ¿Entonces lo que quieres es que te imprima los pokemons clasificados los por comida favorita? Es decir, si agrageste "Pikachu.comida=arroz", "Charizard.comida= carne", "Alakazam.comida=arroz", te mostrara algo como "arroz -> Pikachu, Alakazan | carne -> Charizard"

Comment: No, lo que quiero hacer agruparlos por tipo y comida favorita, ejemplo:('electric', 'Cherry','carne','arroz')
Entoces en ese ejemplo hay tres pokemones electric y su comida favortia

Comment: Aun me dar el error ???

Comment: Deberías de escribir en SO (stack overflow) solamente el código mínimo para reproducir tu error/bug, no todo el programa/script/función. Esto es por dos motivos: 1- Leer tantisimo código da una pereza enorme porque no sabemos en qué parte te falla. Por mucho que lo expliques, hay demasiado que entender de todo ese código. 2- Al reducir el código al mínimo para enseñarnos donde falla, es muy probable que tú mismo veas el error.

Answer (score 0):

Si cuando pides al actor que introduzca el tipo de comida en vez de input usas **raw_input** debería funcionar. Si no la otra opciones es en el print de la p.comida castear la variable a string con **str(p.comida)**.

Espero que ayude saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que te refieres a la función

```
def comida():
    print("Aqui vamos a encontrar a los pokemones por comidas")
    for pokemon in pokemones:
        j = []
        j.append(p.comida)
        j.append(p.comida)
        print(pokemon)
    else:
        pass
    input("Precione enter para ir a menu principa")
    menu()
```

En la línea `print(pokemon)` al ser una instancia de una clase sin método `__str__` o `__repr__` te muestra solo su nombre de clase y su dirección de memoria (ubicación dentro de la memoria RAM del equipo donde se ejecuta tu programa)

Puedes modificar tu clase Pokemon agregando el método faltante:

```
class Pokemon():
    def __init__(self):
        self.nombre = ''
        self.tipo   = ''
        self.latitud = ''
        self.longitud = ''
        self.comida = ''
        self.sangre = ''
        self.ano = ''
        self.mes = ''
        self.dia = ''
        self.edad = ''
        self.signo = ''
        self.foto = ''

    def __str__(self):
        try:
            return f"<Pokemon> {self.nombre} ({self.tipo})"
        except SyntaxError:
            return "<Pokemon> {} ({})".format(self.nombre, self.tipo)
```

Varias aclaraciones:

- Segun las reglas de estilo de Python, los nombres de clases deben estar en CamelCase (todas las palabras juntas con la primera letra de cada palabra en mayúscula, por ejemplo: `Pokemon`, `ClinicaPokemon` `TipoPokemon`, etc)
- Tal como menciona @FJSevilla deberias cambiar tus atributos de clase por atributos de instancia. Comparto su enlace: [Diferencia entre atributos de clase y atributos de instancia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/132570/16617)
- No se si estas usando python 3.6 por lo que coloque dos opciones en el metodo `__str__`. La primera hace uso de los [fstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (en inglés), y en caso de que estes usando una version de python < 3.6.0 hará uso del método `format()` por medio del `except SyntaxError`. Dependiendo de que version tengas deberias elegir una o la otra.