# Duda con alcance de variables en Python

Tags: python-3.x

Antes de nada, agradeceros por la ayuda.

Veréis, tengo el siguiente código:

```py
class Animal():

    def __init__(self, raza, edad, pelaje, tamano): # Características propias de un animal.

        # Con self crearemos una instancia independiente para cada animal.
        self.raza = raza 
        self.edad = edad
        self.pelaje = pelaje
        self.tamano = tamano

        RAZA = "perro" # Constante invariable, que además compartirá todas las instancias de la clase animal. Es decir, una variable para todas las instancias.


    # COMPORTAMIENTOS ¿Qué es capaz de hacer nuestro objeto perro?
    def comer(self, t_hambre):
        self.t_hambre = t_hambre

        if self.t_hambre:
            print(self.nombre, " está comiendo.")
        else:
            print(self.nombre, " no parece tener hambre ahora.")


    def jugar(self):
        print("Estás jugando con ", self.nombre)


    def __necesidades(self):
        print(self.nombre, " ha hecho sus necesidades")


class Mascota(Animal):
    def __init__(self, nombre, dueno, raza, edad, pelaje, tamano):
        super().__init__(raza, edad, pelaje, tamano)
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.dueno = dueno


tobi = Mascota("Tobi", "Juan", "Doberman", 0, "Marrón", "25cm")

tobi.comer(True)
```

El cual solo estoy haciedo a modo orietativo para aprender un poco de POO en python. Bueno, la cuestión es que me he atascado en el alcande que tiene una variable en python, porque ¿Cómo puede ser que una variable creada en una clase que herada de Animal(), en este caso, self.nombre de la clase mascota, sea usada en el método comer, es algo que no entiendo.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`self.nombre` no es un atributo de instancia de la clase `Animal`**, es un atributo de instancia de la clase hija `Mascota`. Tu duda viene porque observas que esta variable se puede usar en el método de instancia `comer` que es heredado de la clase `Animal` la cual no define el atributo.

Pero realmente no hay nada especial en ello, **el atributo se puede usar en el método de instancia de la clase `Mascota` pero no se puede usar en el método de instancia de la clase `Animal`**. Si intentas llamar al método `comer` de `Animal` tendrás una bonita excepción:

> ```
>  >>> animal = Animal("Doberman", 0, "Marrón", "25cm")
>  >>> animal.comer(True)
>
>  Exception has occurred: AttributeError
>      'Animal' object has no attribute 'nombre'
> ```

`Mascota` hereda de `Animal` todos sus métodos y atributos, lo que incluye el método `comer`. Ademas implementa el atributo de instancia `nombre` por lo que puede ser usado en **su método** `comer`.

Realmente el problema es que tu método `comer` (lo mismo ocurre con los otros) no está técnicamente correctamente implementado en `Animal`, simplemente porque intenta hacer uso de un atributo que no existe. Ninguno de los métodos de `Animal` excepto el inicializador se pueden llamar por esta razón.  Si `Animal` no va a tener `nombre` no deberías usarlo en su método.

No obstante hay casos en los que esta forma de actuar está justificada, por ejemplo en el patrón de diseño de "método de la plantilla" (template method design pattern).

Una pequeña aclaración, `RAZA` no es una variable común a todas las instancias, **`RAZA` es una variable local al método `init`** y **deja de existir en el mismo momento que el inicializador retorna**. Una vez inicializada la clase es imposible acceder a la variable RAZA desde ningún lado. El concepto que defines en el comentario:

> "compartirá todas las instancias de la clase animal. Es decir, una
>   variable para todas las instancias"

es precisamente lo que es un atributo de clase, pero este ha de ser definido usando una referencia a la clase (`Animal.RAZA = "perro"` o en un método de clase) o bien fuera de cualquier método:

```
class Animal:
    RAZA = "perro"
```

mirate la siguiente pregunta para más información:

- [Diferencia entre atributos de instancia y atributos de clase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/132561/diferencia-entre-atributos-de-instancia-y-atributos-de-clase/132570#132570)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración. Le echaré un vistazo al link que me has pasado!