# Guardar una clase contenedora que posee una lista dinámica en un archivo binario

Tags: python, archivo

Quiero guardar la siguiente clase en un archivo binario:

```
class Institucion:
    nombre_institucion = "aux"
    datos = []
```

En la lista `datos` se guardan los datos de otra clase:

```
class Estudiante:
    nombre = ""
    apellido = ""
    talle_chomba = ''
    talle_buzo = ''
    importe_total = 0
    senia = 0
    dia_contrato = 0
    mes_contrato = 0
    anio_contrato = 0
    kit_pagado = False

    #Constructor de la clase Estudiante
    def __init__(self, m_nombre, m_apellido, m_talle_chomba, m_talle_buzo,
            m_importe_total, m_senia, m_dia_contrato, m_mes_contrato,
            m_anio_contrato, m_kit_pagado):
    self.nombre = m_nombre
    self.apellido = m_apellido
    self.talle_chomba = m_talle_chomba
    self.talle_buzo = m_talle_buzo
    self.importe_total = m_importe_total
    self.senia = m_senia
    self.dia_contrato = m_dia_contrato
    self.mes_contrato = m_mes_contrato
    self.anio_contrato = m_anio_contrato
    self.kit_pagado = m_kit_pagado
```

He intentado utilizar la función `pickle()` pero sólo se guarda la variable `nombre_institucion` de la primera  clase, no así la lista `datos` con toda la información. Asimismo, he intentado utilizar `bytearray`, y luego escribiendo ese "vector de bytes" en el archivo de manera directa pero tampoco me ha funcionado ya que `bytearray` no podía transformar la información en bytes. ¿Qué me recomiendan para hacer frente a esta situación?

Muchas gracias de antemano por su tiempo y dedicación.

Comment: ¿Usas en ambos casos atributos de clase y no de instancia (que es lo que en principio son) o solo es que simplificaste el código? No es algo trivial  y tampoco cuando se usa pickle, ten en cuenta que un atributo de clase se comparte entre todas las instancias de la clase.

Comment: @FJSevilla Disculpa, pero soy nuevo en Python. Si no entendí mal, tu pregunta es acerca de si trato de guardar atributos de instancia (cada vez que creo una nueva Institución y le cargo información, por ejemplo) o si trato de guardar la clase instanciada pero sin información, ¿cierto?

Comment: Hola Augusto, no, me refiero a que según el código que muestras (por eso preguntaba si habias simplificado), tus atributos son atributos de clase y no de instancia, que es lo que en principio deben ser, mirate: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/132570/15089.

Comment: Hola, @FJSevilla. Disculpa la demora... Creo que luego de leer la explicación me ha quedado más claro. El constructor de la clase `Estudiante` recibe valores y los escribe sobre los atributos de la clase, haciendo en cada caso para cada atributo `self.nombre = nombre`, y así sucesivamente con cada atributo. Dime si no he sido claro.
PD: he incluido el constructor en el código inicial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero de todo, cuando una instancias se serializa con pickle **el código y los datos de la clase (atributos de clase)  no se serializan junto con ellos**. Solo se conservan los datos de la instancia. La razón es que ésto permite modificar la clase añadiendo métodos y no invalidar las instancias serializadas antes.

En tu caso `Institucion` tiene dos atributos **de clase** que no serán serializados adecuadamente. Hay soluciones para ésto, pero no merece la pena complicarse, **ambas clases deberían usar atributos de instancia**, todos ellos conceptualmente lo son ya que son propiedades especificas de un objeto (un estudiante o una institución determinada) no son atributos que todos los estudiantes o instituciones tengan en común (atributos de clase).

En la clase `Estudiante` lo que haces al definir los atributos debajo de la definición de la clase no es inicializarlos, sino que creas atributos de clase que luego solapas con los de instancia en el inicializador y que no vuelves seguramente a usar jamás. Si quieres inicializar, usa argumentos por defecto en el `__init__`.

Para más detalles ver:

- [Diferencia entre atributos de instancia y atributos de clase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/132561/15089)

Por lo tanto tus clases deberían ser algo así:

> ```
> class Institucion:
>
>     def __init__(self, nombre_institucion="aux", datos=None):
>         self.nombre_institucion = nombre_institucion
>         self.datos = datos or []
>
>
> class Estudiante:
>
>     def __init__(
>             self, m_nombre="", m_apellido="", m_talle_chomba="",
>             m_talle_buzo="", m_importe_total=0, m_senia=0, m_dia_contrato=0,
>             m_mes_contrato=0, m_anio_contrato=0, m_kit_pagado=False):
>         self.nombre = m_nombre
>         self.apellido = m_apellido
>         self.talle_chomba = m_talle_chomba
>         self.talle_buzo = m_talle_buzo
>         self.importe_total = m_importe_total
>         self.senia = m_senia
>         self.dia_contrato = m_dia_contrato
>         self.mes_contrato = m_mes_contrato
>         self.anio_contrato = m_anio_contrato
>         self.kit_pagado = m_kit_pagado
> ```

Con ello no hay problema alguno con usar pickle, todo en las clases es serializable:

```
import pickle


inst = Institucion("Unicornios SAU")
estu1 = Estudiante("Fulanito", "Pérez", "M", "M", 25, 3, 30, 2, 2020, False)
estu2 = Estudiante("Menganito", "García", "G", "G", 45, 4, 62, 3, 2019, True) 
inst.datos.append(estu1)
inst.datos.append(estu2)


with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(inst, file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Para volver tus objetos a la vida, debs tener en cuenta que las clases deben estar definidas en el módulo que las intenta deserializar desde el archivo binario, directamente o importándolas desde otro módulo, pero tienen que estar accesibles en el namespace global

```
import pickle



class Institucion:

    def __init__(self, nombre_institucion="aux", datos=None):
        self.nombre_institucion = nombre_institucion
        self.datos = datos or []


class Estudiante:

    def __init__(
            self, m_nombre="", m_apellido="", m_talle_chomba="",
            m_talle_buzo="", m_importe_total=0, m_senia=0, m_dia_contrato=0,
            m_mes_contrato=0, m_anio_contrato=0, m_kit_pagado=False):
        self.nombre = m_nombre
        self.apellido = m_apellido
        self.talle_chomba = m_talle_chomba
        self.talle_buzo = m_talle_buzo
        self.importe_total = m_importe_total
        self.senia = m_senia
        self.dia_contrato = m_dia_contrato
        self.mes_contrato = m_mes_contrato
        self.anio_contrato = m_anio_contrato
        self.kit_pagado = m_kit_pagado


with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as file:
    inst = pickle.load(file)
```

Y ya ésta:

> ```
> >>> inst
> <__main__.Institucion object at 0x7f9b8c676c70>
>
> >>> inst.datos
> [<__main__.Estudiante object at 0x7f9b8c676b20>, <__main__.Estudiante object at 0x7f9b8c676ac0>]
>
> >>> inst.nombre_institucion
> 'Unicornios SAU'
>
> >>> inst.datos[0].nombre
> 'Fulanito'
>
> >>> inst.datos[1].apellido
> 'García'
> ```

Tal como lo planteas, podrías usar dataclasses:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
import pickle


@dataclass
class Institucion:
    nombre_institucion: str = "aux"
    datos: list = field(default_factory=list)


@dataclass
class Estudiante:
    m_nombre: str = ""
    m_apellido: str = ""
    m_talle_chomba: str = ""
    m_talle_buzo: str = ""
    m_importe_total: int = 0
    m_senia: int = 0
    m_dia_contrato: int = 0
    m_mes_contrato: int = 0
    m_anio_contrato: int = 0
    m_kit_pagado: bool = False


inst = Institucion("Unicornios SAU")
estu1 = Estudiante("Fulanito", "Pérez", "M", "M", 25, 3, 30, 2, 2020, False)
estu2 = Estudiante("Menganito", "García", "G", "G", 45, 4, 62, 3, 2019, True)
inst.datos.append(estu1)
inst.datos.append(estu2)


with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(inst, file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

---

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
import pickle


@dataclass
class Institucion:
    nombre_institucion: str = "aux"
    datos: list = field(default_factory=list)


@dataclass
class Estudiante:
    m_nombre: str = ""
    m_apellido: str = ""
    m_talle_chomba: str = ""
    m_talle_buzo: str = ""
    m_importe_total: int = 0
    m_senia: int = 0
    m_dia_contrato: int = 0
    m_mes_contrato: int = 0
    m_anio_contrato: int = 0
    m_kit_pagado: bool = False

with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as file:
    inst = pickle.load(file)
```

---

> ```
> >>> inst
>
> Institucion(
>     nombre_institucion='Unicornios SAU',
>     datos=[
>         Estudiante(
>             m_nombre='Fulanito',
>             m_apellido='Pérez',
>             m_talle_chomba='M',
>             m_talle_buzo='M',
>             m_importe_total=25,
>             m_senia=3,
>             m_dia_contrato=30,
>             m_mes_contrato=2,
>             m_anio_contrato=2020,
>             m_kit_pagado=False),
>         Estudiante(
>             m_nombre='Menganito',
>             m_apellido='García',
>             m_talle_chomba='G',
>             m_talle_buzo='G',
>             m_importe_total=45,
>             m_senia=4, m_dia_contrato=62,
>             m_mes_contrato=3,
>             m_anio_contrato=2019,
>             m_kit_pagado=True)
>             ])
> ```

Comment: He probado la primer recomendación y como era de esperarse, ¡funciona! Sin embargo, me ha surgido la duda sobre qué método de guardado/lectura es más recomendable en este caso.

Comment: Hola Augusto, ¿a qué te refieres con "método de guardado/lectura más recomendable"? ¿Otra forma de implementarlo usando pickle? ¿Alternativas a pickle?

Comment: Me he expresado mal. No era un método de guardado/lectura sino cómo definir la clase. Has mencionado que puedo utilizar dataclasses. Esa era mi pregunta.

Comment: Ok,  si tus clases tienen mucha lógica aparte incorporada en métodos, creo que no merece la pena que te compliques.

Comment: Lo mencionaba, porque según lo que mostrabas, tus clases aparentan ser contenedores de datos estructurados más que nada y en estos casos el uso de dataclasses facilita la tarea mucho al implementar muchos métodos por ti, por ejemplo,si te fijas no necesitas el inicializador si solo se usa para asignar valores o inicializar los atributos o `__repr__`, además de permitir congelar la instancia (frozen), convertirla en diccionario o tupla o volver a generar instancias  a partir de dichos diccionarios o tuplas, etc.