# ¿Por qué recibo el error ":RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded"?

Tags: python, poo, class

```
from typing import List, Tuple, Dict, Union

class CatalogueException(Exception):
    pass

class StockException(Exception):
    pass

class Product():
    def __init__(self,_code,_name,_price):
        self._code=_code
        self._name=_name
        self._price=_price

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._code)
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Code: {}\nName: {}\nPrice: {}'.format(self._code,self._name,self._price)
class Catalogue():
    catalogo=[]

    def add_product(self,p):
        catalogo=[]
        if p in catalogo:
            print("el producto")
        catalogo.append(p)

    def remove_product(self,p):
        catalogo.remove(p)

    def __str__(self):
        return('{}'.format(catalogo))

catalogo=Catalogue()
new_spanner = Product("S78", "Adjustable spanner", 35.99)
new_hammer = Product("A45", 'Bush hammer', 15.5)
catalogo.add_product(new_spanner)
catalogo.add_product(new_hammer)
print(catalogo)
```

Lo que se intenta es que imprima los dos productos añadidos al catalogo y quede de la manera:

```
Code: A45 
Name: Bush hammer 
Price: 15.5 
Code: S78 
Name: Adjustable spanner 
Price: 35.99
```

Pero al ejecutar sale el error:

> :RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

He probado a reescribir la funcion str de diferentes maneras pero me sale el mismo error

Comment: Sería interesante que leyeras [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y marcaras como aceptada una respuesta si te ayudó a resolver el problema. En particular, [la respuesta de FJSevilla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/355563/83) es muy completa y bien merece esa marca

Comment: Habia votado pero desde luego que se merece la marca.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en la línea

```
return('{}'.format(catalogo))
```

pero viene de antes, implementas mal la clase.

### Declaras un **atributo de clase** que luego no usas

```
class Catalogue():
    catalogo=[]
    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

para empezar no debe ser un atributo de clase sino de instancia, dado que **cada objeto catálogo tendrá sus productos** y no todos los catálogos los mismos productos (atributo de clase).

Además de ello, jamás llegas a usarlo realmente, ésto se debe a que no lo referencias desde los métodos con `instancia.catalogo` (`self.catalogo`) o `Catalogue.catalogo` (`cls.catalogo`).

Mírate ésta pregunta para entender la diferencia entre ambos tipos de atributos:

- [Diferencia entre atributos de instancia y atributos de clase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/132561/15089)

### En los métodos de instancia usas realmente la **variable global** `catalogo`

```
class Catalogue():

    def remove_product(self,p):
        catalogo.remove(p)
        #^^^^^^^
        #  esto

    def __str__(self):
        return('{}'.format(catalogo))
                          #^^^^^^^^
                          # y ésto
catalogo=Catalogue()
#^^^^^^^^
# son ésto
```

**ésta es la razón de que termines con una recursión infinita**:

- `print(producto)` llama a `producto.__str__`.
- Cuándo se evalúa `return('{}'.format(catalogo))` `str.format` llama a `producto.__str__`  de nuevo.
- Y así hasta el infinito y más allá, bueno hasta que llegas a 1000 llamadas recursivas que es el límite por defecto que tiene Python para proteger al propio intérprete de un desbordamiento de pila.

### En el método `add_product` realmente no haces nada

Sí haces realmente, pero no hay efectos fuera del mismo. Aunque `catalogo` es una variable global como se ha explicado, al hacer `catalogo = []` (reasignación) se crea automáticamente una variable local al método que solapa la global, luego añades el producto a la lista, pero como buena variable local, en cuanto el método retorna el GC manda a la lista a mejor vida. Esa lista jamás podrá ser accedida desde fuera del método.

En definitiva, debes usar un atributo de instancia y no de clase, el código podría quedar así, con anotaciones de tipo incluidas:

```
from typing import List, Union


class CatalogueException(Exception):
    pass


class StockException(Exception):
    pass


class Product:
    def __init__(self, code: str, name: str, price: Union[float, int]):
        self._code: str = code
        self._name: str = name
        self._price: Union[float, int] = price

    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return hash(self._code)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'Code: {self._code}\nName: {self._name}\nPrice: {self._price}'


class Catalogue:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._products: List[Product] = []

    def add_product(self, product: Product) -> None:
        self._products.append(product)

    def remove_product(self, product: Product) -> None:
        self._products.remove(product)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        prods = "\n\n".join(str(prod) for prod in self._products)
        return f"{'-' * 34} CATÁLOGO {'-' * 34}\n{prods}\n{'-' * 78}"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    catalogo = Catalogue()
    new_spanner = Product("S78", "Adjustable spanner", 35.99)
    new_hammer = Product("A45", 'Bush hammer', 15.5)
    catalogo.add_product(new_spanner)
    catalogo.add_product(new_hammer)
    print(catalogo)
```

Es recomendable que no uses `catalogo` como nombre del atributo de la clase `Catalogo`, es confuso. `products` es un mejor nombre para la lista.

El uso de `_nombre` es una convención para marcar atributos/métodos "privados". Es correcto su uso, pero no tiene sentido en el nombre de los argumentos en este caso.

Answer (score 2):

Estás instanciando incorrectamente el objeto: cuando defines una clase Clase, lo que tienes es un objeto. A partir de allí, trabajas con el objeto asignándole valores, etc. Esa definición se hace cuando defines `objeto = Clase()` y se define en `__init__()`. Sin embargo, tú estás definiendo variables de clase.

Por ello, deberías decir algo así como:

```
class Catalogue():
    def __init__(self):
        self.catalogo = []
```

Y luego trabajar con `self.catalogo` todo el rato:

```
    def add_product(self, p):
        if p in self.catalogo:
            print("el producto")
        self.catalogo.append(p)

    def remove_product(self, p):
        self.catalogo.remove(p)
```

Finalmente, para mostrar los valores está bien que uses `__str__()`, pero hay que darle alguna vuelta:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '\n'.join(['{}'.format(cat) for cat in self.catalogo])
```

Answer (score 0):

Has llegado al limite de la recursividad por eso te lanza ese error.
Para solventarlo puedes hacer esto:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(30000) # 10000 es un ejemplo puedes variar el numero incrementando o decrementando
```

Pero es mas recomendable que optimices el código ya que esto puede afectar a la velocidad del mismo