# ¿Como reutilizar una función que sirve de menú dentro de una clase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

Quería hacerlo como en java pero Python no tiene `do while`, entonces se me ocurrió con una función:

```
class trys:

    def menu():
      print("welcome to your soccer team")
      print("1 team trip")
      print("2 training")
      print("3 football game")
      print("4 plan training")
      print("5 interview")
      print("6 heal lesson")

    menu()
```

el método:

```
    def method(self):
        option = int(input("type your option :"))
        while option <0 or option >6:
          menu()

p = trys()
p.method()
```

quiero que si el usuario digita un numero diferente a los que están en pantalla me llame a la función para no tener que volver a pegar el código. pero me sale esto:

> NameError: name 'menu' is not defined

Comment: No uso python pero segun entiendo deberia funcionar... no tiene sentido,  ¿Esta todo tu codigo en el mismo archivo y ademas la funcion la defines antes de usarla?

Comment: ¿Dónde defines la función exactamente? Sin ver la estructura del código es imposible saber que está pasando, lo que sabemos es que cuando el íntérprete ejecuta  `menu()` en el método de instancia `method()` dicha función no ha sido definida en ese namespace...

Comment: @Riven veo que todo esta bien, hay agrege la clase y la instancia

Comment: el programa cae cuando digito un numero diferente a los que estan en pantalla

Comment: @FJSevilla la verdad el codigo no se pero lo de las clases tienes razon me enpendeje con las clases

Comment: Ah ahora entiendo lo que pasa... es que menu era un metodo,  no una funcion... recuerda que python es sensible a la identacion,  si no identas correctamente pasaran cosas asi.

Comment: @Riven ententido, menu si era una funcion por eso no tenia el self y esa era mi intencion llamarla desde cualquier metodo muchas veces

Comment: muchas gracias a todos por su valioso tiempo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de entrar en el problema en si, tienes un ciclo infinito:

```
def method():
    option = int(input("type your option :"))

    while option <0 or option >6: #̣ opcion es la variable de control del ciclo
                                  #--|
        menu()                    #  |-- Nunca se modifica dentro del mismo
                                  #--|
```

Dicho ésto, `menu` es un "atributo de clase" tal como está definido, para acceder a él desde el método de instancia, debes hacerlo tal como está usando la referencia a la clase:

```
trys.menu()
```

- [Diferencia entre atributos de instancia y atributos de clase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/132561/15089)

Además nunca haga ésto:

```
class trys:

    def menu():
        print("welcome to your soccer team")
        print("1 team trip")
        print("2 training")
        print("3 football game")
        print("4 plan training")
        print("5 interview")
        print("6 heal lesson")

    menu() # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

El **cuerpo de una clase se evalúa y ejecuta en tiempo de definición**, cuando se ejecuta o importa el módulo, no cuando la clase se instancia. Por lo tanto, cuando importes el módulo que contiene a clase o lo ejecutes aparecerá un bonito menú en stdout sin haber instanciado siquiera la clase, y eso normalmente no lo queremos...

Normalmente los menús y entradas de usuario que se suelen usar para generar objetos de las clases no se colocan dentro de la clase, sino como meras funciones en el modulo, dejando la clase solo para representar el objeto en si.

Si dejas el menú en la clase, lo suyo es posiblemente que lo definas como método estático ya que no maneja ni atributos de clase (método de clase) ni atributos de instancia (método de instancia):

```
class Trys:

    @staticmethod
    def menu():
        print("welcome to your soccer team")
        print("1 team trip")
        print("2 training")
        print("3 football game")
        print("4 plan training")
        print("5 interview")
        print("6 heal lesson")

    def method(self):
        option = 0
        while not 0 < option < 7:
            self.menu()
            option = int(input("type your option: "))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Trys()
    p.method()
```

Los métodos estáticos en Python son funciones normales que tienen alguna relación lógica con la clase, pero que realmente no son parte esencial de ella ya que no modifican o acceden a atributos de instancia o clase y por tanto no modifican el comportamiento del objeto o clase. Podrían definirse fuera sin problemas pero nos conviene por legibilidad o cualquier otra razón que formen parte de la misma. Se puede acceder a ellos mediante una referencia a la clase o comúnmente mediante una referencia a la instancia (`self` en éste caso), pero no reciben como argumento automáticamente ni una referencia a la clase ni a la instancia (métodos de clase y métodos de instancia respectivamente).

Aunque no vendría mal tener en cuenta que los usuarios son "malvados por naturaleza" y tener en cuenta que puede ingresar algo que no sea un entero.

```
def method(self):
    option = 0
    while not 0 < option < 7:
        self.menu()
        try:
            option = int(input("type your option: "))
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

o directamente quitarse el problema de la conversión de encima y usar cadenas directamente para diferenciar las opciones del menú.

```
def method(self):
    option = ""
    while not opción in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'):
        self.menu()
        option = input("type your option: ")
```

en éste caso valdría también:

```
    def method(self):
        option = ''
        while not '0' < option < '7':
            self.menu()
            option = input("type your option: ")
```

pero no si tienes más de 9 opciones, ya que las cadenas se ordena según orden lexicográfico, por lo que `2 > 10`.

Por último, por convención los nombres de las clases usan siempre CamelCase:

- [PEP 8 - Naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

Answer (score 1):

Porqué no usa `self.menu()`?

En efecto Python no nos obliga a usar clases, pero si desea hacer uso de ellas debería tener en cuenta que el método `menu()` pertenece a la instancia `self` de su clase `trys`:

```
class trys:

    def menu(self):
      print("welcome to your soccer team")
      print("1 team trip")
      print("2 training")
      print("3 football game")
      print("4 plan training")
      print("5 interview")
      print("6 heal lesson")

    def method(self):
        self.menu()
        option = int(input("type your option :"))
        while option < 0 or option > 6:
            self.method()
            break;

foo = trys()
foo.method()
```

Answer (score 1):

Pueden haber otras maneras de hacerlo pero esta tambien puede ser una buena opcion, espero te sirva

```
class Menu:

    def __init__(self):

        print("welcome to your soccer team...\nSelect a option:\n1 team trip\n2 training\n3 football game\n4 plan training\n5 interview\n6 heal lesson")

        self.opcion = 0

    def medoto(self):

        self.opcion = int(input("What option do you want to choose?:\n"))

        while self.opcion <= 0 or self.opcion > 6:

            self.opcion = int(input("Bad choice, choose another option:"))

        else:

            print("Good choice")

objeto = Menu()
objeto.medoto()
```