# No se muestran los widgets en my aplicación Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Estoy aprendiendo a usar la librería kivy de Python, pero me enfrento a un extraño problema. Los widgets no aparecen cuando se ejecuta el código. Lo he instalado desde el cmd cómo dicen las [instrucciones en su sitio](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html#install-pip) y lo he hecho desde [la terminal de VS Code](https://youtu.be/lQkjroaPz80?si=0xyNi8L8fuQfeQPb); pensando que podría deberse a que estaba mal instalado, sin embargo, el problema persiste, los widgets no aparecen.

Voy a dejar dos versiones de mi código para que puedan verlo y orientarme, aquí está creando solo una etiqueta:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Grilla(GridLayout):
      def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(Grilla, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.cols=2
            self.add_widget(Label(text='Hola mundo!'))
            self.Entry_nombre=TextInput
            self.add_widget(self.Entry_nombre)

            
class Basic_app(App):
    def constructor(self):
            

            # Add the label to the box layout.
            label=Label(text='Hola mundo')

            return label
            
    
app= Basic_app()
app.run()
```

Y aquí se los dejo llamando a una entrada de texto, en ninguno de los dos casos la ventana muestra los widgets:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Grilla(GridLayout):
      def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(Grilla, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.cols=2
            self.add_widget(Label(text='Hola mundo!'))
            self.Entry_nombre=TextInput
            self.add_widget(self.Entry_nombre)

            
class Basic_app(App):
    def constructor(self):
            

            # Add the label to the box layout.
            label=Label(text='Hola mundo')

            return Grilla
            
    
app= Basic_app()
app.run()
```

, intenté solucionarlos con IA, pero simplemente me dijo que agregara un layout que no solucionó nada, reitero el hecho de que la terminal no me da ningún error, todo parece estar funcionando correctamente. Cualquiera que pueda ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente tienes dos errores (uno repetido dos veces):

- En tu clase `Grilla`:

  ```
  self.Entry_nombre=TextInput
  ```

  no estas instanciando la clase, la instanciación de clases usa la misma notación que para llamar a funciones:

  ```
  self.Entry_nombre = TextInput()
  ```
- En `Basic_app` defines un método `constructor` que jamas es llamado. Ni tu lo llamas explícitamente, ni es un método especial que sea llamado automáticamente por el interprete de Python o por kivy. El "constructor" en Python es el método `__init__`, aunque es una verdad a medias, si te interesa profundizar mirate:

  [¿Qué es un constructor?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63407/qu%c3%a9-es-un-constructor/63451#63451)

  No obstante, en la subclase de `App` de kivy lo que tienes que implementar obligatoriamente es el método [`App.build`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.build). Dicho método debe retornar el widget base de tu app, en tu caso una instancia de `Grilla`.

  Este método tiene una función muy importante ya que es el método  establecido en Kivy para construir la app. Es llamado automáticamente (una sola vez) al iniciar tu app con `App.run()` y es usado para obtener el árbol de widgets de tu app. Al no implementar este método no se obtiene ningún widget base del que partir, por lo que tu aplicación sera una ventana vacía.
- En el método `constructor` (que debe ser `build`), retornas de nuevo una referencia a la clase y no una instancia de ella, en vez de:

  ```
    return Grilla
  ```

  debe ser:

  ```
    return Grilla()
  ```

El código quedaría algo así:

```
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Grilla(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Hola mundo!'))
        self.entry_nombre = TextInput()
        self.add_widget(self.entry_nombre)

            
class BasicApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Grilla()
            
    
app = BasicApp()
app.run()
```

Para tu primer ejemplo, simplemente seria lo comentado en el segundo punto:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class BasicApp(App):
    def build(self):
        label = Label(text='Hola mundo')
        return label

app = BasicApp()
app.run()
```

**Nota:** No es necesario pasar explícitamente una referencia de la clase y de la instancia a `super` en Python 3 con herencia simple. Eso era necesario para el difunto Python 2 solamente.

Comment: Ya entendí @FJSevilla, los tutoriales que había visto tienen uno o dos años de viejos, gracias por la ayuda